# System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter Gets null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I used @@ROWCOUNT in my stored procedure to get the number of selected rows and it returns the affected rows correctly:

```
Select @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

I'm calling this sp in C# as bellow:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Result> Search(out int totalRecords)
        {
            totalRecords = 0;
            var RowCount = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("RowCount", totalRecords.GetType());
            var result = DB.Search(RowCount);

            totalRecords = (int)RowCount.Value;

            return result;
        }
```

The result is returned correctly, but I don't know why the RowCount.Value is null.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

RowCount is just an ObjectParameter which you pass to your object query or query builder method. It's not meant to return any result of the query execution and after the query has been compiled, the value cannot be changed anymore. Because you create it by passing the parameter's type instead of a specific object, Value is initalized with null and remains null.